# raspberry pi temporary failure in name resolution using both cloudflare and google DNS services

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, raspberry-pi

I wrote a script to scrape a certain website. 
After several days I have started to get this `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`. I have tried to switch to Google DNS (8.8.8.8) and Cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1), but no luck.
Furthermore, different computers on the same WIFI can access the website without problems.

Any ideas?